# Complex Analysis: Does the closed curve of contour integral matter the result?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

In the proof of Cauchy's Integral Formula:
$$\oint_C{f(z)\over{z-a}}dz$$
The video said that it would be equals to:
$$\oint_\Gamma{f(z)\over{z-a}}dz$$
where $\Gamma$ is a circle centred at $a$.

My question is: Why can the integral with a unknown $C$(closed curve) can be rewritten with form $\Gamma$ which is not same as $C$? Then if it is true, does the path affect the final result?

Comment: Look up homotopies & Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: It's not true for any $C.$ It is true for any $C$ that goes around $a$ exactly once in the counter-clockwise (assuming $\Gamma$ fgoes around oil counter-clockwise direction) and doesn't go around any poles of $f.$

Comment: You have neglected to state any conditions on the function f(z) or on where it is defined. And you have not stated how C and  are related. These determine whether the formula you have not stated is true or not.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[image]

From the picture, $\int _{C_n \cup \Gamma_n} \frac{f(z)}{z-a} = 0$ by Cauchy Theorem since there is no poles within $C_n \cup \Gamma_n$.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int _{C_n \cup \Gamma_n} \frac{f(z)}{z-a} =  \int _{C \cup -\Gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z-a} = \int _{C} \frac{f(z)}{z-a} - \int _{\Gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z-a} = 0$

Hence both integrals are equal since there are no poles in the region between $C$ and $\Gamma$.

Now the same argument extends for arbitrary $C$ and $\Gamma$ other than the nice circles drawn for illustration.

The integrals are same assuming the region between $C$ and $\Gamma$ has no poles and winding number of both $C$ and $\Gamma$ is $1$.

Comment: Late comment, but we don't know any conditions on $f$ or how $C$ and $\Gamma$ are related (if they even are). What is $n$ and why are there two line segments?

Comment: The diagram is only for illustration. We cut the curve $C$ and $\Gamma$ at 2 points and remove the piece of curve between the points and we join them across the curves to apply cauchy formula. As $n$ tends to $\infty$ the points at which cut is made comes closer and closer and points at which cut is made becomes arbitrarily close eventually.

Comment: What exactly are $C_n$ and $\Gamma_n$? I'm not convinced the endpoints of the curves join together as $n$ goes to infinity. It's not clear what happens to the two line segments, either.

Comment: The endpoints join together by construction and there is nothing to prove here. The point where cut is made need to follow the curve as $n$ increases and reach the other point by construction. When line segments join the integral along the line segments are in opposite direction so they cancel out mathematically.